# Android Bitmap transparent background is black on lower API versions

Tags: android, xml, bitmap, drawable, alpha

I'm trying to make a splash screen using a bitmap like I normally do.  However, the transparent layer shows up as black on API 16 (not sure what other API versions are affected).

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_skull"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

[image: Bitmaps]

[image: Original Bitmaps]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  I had converted the SVG into a bitmap.  Converted it into a PNG and it worked just fine.